# Visual Studio exits debug on exception

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, emgucv

I have an x64 application using latest EmguCV 3 and after calling `DetectAndCompute` on `FastDetector` i get an Exception but unfortunately i don't know what Exception it was because as sun as Exception occurs Visual Studio (VS 2015 Community) exits debug (although i can see Excpetion Details window appearing for a brief fraction of a second before it exits.) All that is in the output window after it exits is: `The program has exited with code 0 (0x0).` In Exception settings I have checked all `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`. How can I retrieve information about this exception ?

Comment: Is exception giving any inner exception?

Comment: do you use more then one thread? It could be that the thread with the exception is forcefully killed by another while its being held by the debugger. If not and if you know where the exception is you can always temperately put a try/catch around it to print the exception to the console/debug

Comment: Thats the thing, I can't. Its already surrounded with a try/catch clause, but as soon as exception is thrown/cautch Visual Studio exits debug so I can't really see what Exception was thrown and what was the Inner Exception if any. I'm thinking it might be due to the fact that my application process is being killed by OS due to some fatal error such as segmentation fault. In that scenario what are the options to retrieve information about that Exception/Error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this behavior isn't caused by some segfaults or similar things that might cause the application to fail fast or to be killed hard by the OS, as supposed.

The process that fails is the **StandardCollector.Service.exe**. This is the performance data collection tool that runs automatically on every debug session in Visual Studio 2015.

The exception code is hereby `0xc000000d` which means `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. That's exactly what OpenCV throws.

In order to see the original exception, you should start your application without debugger attached. Your code (which causes the exception) should be placed in a try-catch block, and in the exception handler you should simply log the error to a file or whatever you're using for logging.